# IFrame wont go fullscreen

Tags: html, iframe

so i'm making a shell shockers site for my friends in school, and it wont go fullscreen
this is the code iv used. whats wrong??? (I'm sorry if its a simple fix but I used what I saw online to allow this and it doesn't work)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    </head>
    <body>
<iframe src="https://playminigames.ru/en/embed/shell-shockers" style="width: 1200px; height: 700px;" frameborder="0" allow="fullscreen" object-fit:screen;></iframe>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: `allow="fullscreen"` may help. [ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Feature_Policy/Using_Feature_Policy#the_iframe_allow_attribute)

Comment: @onkarruikar i have that in there, idk why it doesnt work tho?? the link to the site is https://chainzgames.w3spaces.com/Shell.html

Comment: It does go fullscreen when I click the fullscreen button on top right corner, next to settings button. Do you expect it to go fullscreen automatically?

Comment: no, i clicked it and iv been on it for an hour and it isn't full screen @onkarruikar